# json_decode from python script returning null

Tags: php, python, json, laravel, null

I have a python script that returns JSON like that:

```
{
    "2013": "34 124 682,7", 
    "2014": "39 656 349,2", 
    "2015": "34 452 255,0", 
    "2016": "55 921 181,4", 
    "2017": "27 026 543,1", 
    "2018": "7 009 560,3"
}
```

In my Controller:

```
$json = shell_exec("C:/Users/1/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/python -W ignore ../../../interprises_parsers/parsers/tax/parser.py ".$bin);

$output = json_decode($json);

return $output;
```

Returns me null! Paths are correct! Bin is number also correct!

P.S. Executing script in system console, gives me correct JSON output

**UPDATE:** I got JSON from my script, but when i return it as json_decode variable it gives me next error: 
*The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "object" given.*

Here is my var_dump:

```
object(stdClass)#462 (6) { ["2013"]=> string(4) "11,9" ["2014"]=> string(4) "11,9" ["2015"]=> string(4) "12,9" ["2016"]=> string(4) "11,9" ["2017"]=> string(3) "3,5" ["2018"]=> string(4) "30,0" } {"2013": "11,9", "2014": "11,9", "2015": "12,9", "2016": "11,9", "2017": "3,5", "2018": "30,0"}
```

Comment: why not use json_decode then?

Comment: i forgot to add it. check it again pls

Comment: if you var_dump $json. What is the output? Is it the string above?

Comment: it gives me Null

Comment: Well then this question has nothing to do with php as I see it. The problem is with the execution of the pythonscript or the pythonscript itself.

Comment: Andreas, when i execute this script in console i have correct JSON output! I think the problem is in PHP

Comment: according to [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php), the return for `shell_exec` is "The output from the executed command or NULL if an error occurred or the command produces no output."

Comment: _"when i execute this script in console"_ - Which script? The PHP-script or the Python script? It might also be that your web server user don't have permission to run that file at that location.

Comment: Now i have next problem. I got some values from shell_exec, now whenever i do return from controller it gives error "The Response content must be a string "

Comment: shell_exec returns the output from the executed command or NULL if an error occurred or the command produces no output.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for me is:
I had to use next code in my controller :

```
$output = json_decode($json, true);
```

and in my View

```
<tbody v-for="(tax,index) in taxes">
  <tr>
    <td>{{index}}</td>
    <td>{{tax}}</td>                                            
  </tr>                                          
</tbody>
```

since i use Vue js! Thank you everyone!